# which ffmpeg version for cobalt on arm?

Tags: ffmpeg, cobalt

when we build cobalt with arm toolchain, we got some error compilation messages as below.
ffmpeg_video_decoder.cc:41:33: error: 'PIX_FMT_YUV420P' was not declared in this scope
ffmpeg_video_decoder.cc:61:10: error: 'AVFrame {aka struct AVFrame}' has no member named 'base'

ffmpeg version we try are "3.2" and "3.0.2" but they got above error message.
we search ffmpeg header files for these error messages, seem ffmpeg check (LIBAVUTIL_VERSION_MAJOR < 53) in "libavutil/version.h".

could you give us some suggestion?

Comment: Try old release [2.3.6](https://ffmpeg.org/olddownload.html) or attempt to update the cobalt source to use recent FFmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Cobalt uses:

- libavcodec 54.35.0
- libavformat 54.20.4
- libavutil 52.3.0
- libavresample 1.0.1